# Insert function in excel does not have a list for all functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016, and I can successfully use the [DateDif](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-datedif-function) function.

But this function does not appear in the list of functions:

- For example, it's not available in the "insert function" table.

[image: insert function]

- And when typing the function, Excel doesn't suggest it in the drop down menu.

[image: datedif]

Why is this?!

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: From: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c  'Warning: Excel provides the DATEDIF function in order to support older workbooks from Lotus 1-2-3. The DATEDIF function may calculate incorrect results under certain scenarios. Please see the known issues section of this article for further details.'  Seems to be a legacy item and is buggy.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, I thought my excel was acting up and no matter what I googled, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I think the only version in which `DATEDIF` appeared in the formula menu (along with `HELP` for the function), was Excel 2000.

Comment: @Shayan,, Microsoft has been officially included the `DATEDIF` funtion with `Excel 2016` and is available in Help also. But It doesn't appear in Function list though. Hence, it doesn't pop up also the syntax of `DATEDIF` is written.